# Complex structure with a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

A complex structure on a real vector space $V$ is a linear endomorphism $J$ of $V$ such that $J^2=−1$, where $1$ is the identity transformation of $V.$ Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation such that $T$ commutes with $J.$ Prove that det $T>0$

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean $T$ isn't the zero transformation.

**Hint**: Here's the answer for $V = \mathbb R^2$, outlined in the steps below.

1. $J$ necessarily(see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Complex_planes_in_M(2,_%E2%84%9D)) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302358/nice-parameterization-of-linear-complex-structures-on-the-real-plane)) has the form $\begin{bmatrix}
   a & b\\ 
   c & -a
   \end{bmatrix}$, with determinant = 1.
2. $T$ commutes with $J$ [if and only if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Complex_planes_in_M(2,_%E2%84%9D)) $T = xI_2+yJ$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb R$.

   - First note that $c \ne 0$. Then, for $T = \begin{bmatrix}
     j & f\\ 
     g & h
     \end{bmatrix}$, choose $x=j-ay$ and $y=\frac gc$.
3. By Steps 1 and 2, $\det T = x^2 + y^2$. This is always nonnegative, and is positive if and only if $T$ is not the zero transformation.