# Matrix representation of complex structures

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis

Let $J$ be a matrix representation of a linear complex structure ($J^2= -I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix). In the case of the $2\times 2$ real matrices a general complex structure can be written as: 
$$
J=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b\sqrt{1+a^2} \\
    -\frac{1}{b}\sqrt{1+a^2} & -a \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Is there a similar parametrization for higher dimensional matrices? In particular for a $4\times 4$ matrix?

Comment: Note: Related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3544967/formula-for-anti-involutive-almost-complex-structures-and-involutive-maps-on-a)

Comment: Sandro Vitenti, did you ever figure out the answer?